# Count number of non-null values in each column of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count, array-column

Let's say I have an array:

```
[
  {0:1, 1:5, 3:null},
  {0:4, 1:null, 3:null},
  {0:null, 1:5, 3:5}
]
```

I want to count non-null values per associative key so that my expected output is:

```
[{0:2, 1:2, 3:1}]
```

Comment: 1) What have you tried? 2) How do you get to that calculation?

Comment: Should the output for 1 be 10 (i.e. 5+5)?

Comment: _I want to count..._ What do you want to count?

Comment: i want to count value in same index. so its like count cell in excel from top to bottom.

Comment: Then shouldn't the expected output be: `[{0:5, 1:10, 3:7}]`?

Comment: Do you mean the sum of the values or count?

Comment: @icecub yes,, that what i mean. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it will find the sum even if one key exists in only one array as well. This will find both the sum and the counts.

```
<?php

$arr = [
  [0 => 1, 1 => 5, 3 => null],
  [0 => 4, 1 => null, 3 => null],
  [0 => null, 1 => 5, 3 => 5]
];
$out   = [];
$count = [];
foreach ( $arr as $key => $value) {
    # code...
    foreach ( $value as $k => $v) {
      if(NULL != $v) {
         $count[$k] = isset($count[$k]) ? ($count[$k] + 1) : 1;
      }

      $v       = (NULL === $v) ? 0 : $v;
      $out[$k] = isset($out[$k]) ? ($out[$k] + $v) : $v;

   }

}
echo '<pre>';
echo "Sum array is : ";
print_r($out);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
echo "Count array is : ";
print_r($count);
echo '</pre>';
```

Will gives the output

```
Sum array is : 
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 10
    [3] => 5
)

Count array is : 
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
    [3] => 1
)
```

And for the input array commented below

```
    $arr = [ 
    [0 => null, 1 => null, 3 => null], 
    [0 => 4, 1 => null, 3 => null], 
    [0 => null, 1 => 5, 3 => 5] 
];
```

Will give

```
Sum array is : 
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 5
    [3] => 5
)

Count array is : 
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [3] => 1
)
```

**If this is not what you want give the expected output for the commented array as well.**

Comment: It work, but when the array change it not work at all. example, first array value is null it make it except the value. Sorry for my bad english. Do you understand what i'm say.

Comment: $arr = [
  [0 => null, 1 => null, 3 => null],
  [0 => 4, 1 => null, 3 => null],
  [0 => null, 1 => 5, 3 => 5]
];

Comment: @WayanTisna Please see the updated answer. Please post the expected output for that array if my output is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1) Loop over the array. You will get sub arrays.

2) Loop over sub arrays, we will get actual numerical values.

3) Prepare an array with key as numerical value in the sub arrays.

4) Every time in the inner loop, if the value exists as key in the result array.

5) If exists, increase the count.

This could be your solution:

```
<?php
$arr = [
  [0 => 1, 1 => 5, 3 => null],
  [0 => 4, 1 => null, 3 => 2],
  [0 => null, 1 => 5, 3 => 5]
];
$out = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2){
        $index = $value2;
        if (array_key_exists($index, $out)){
            $out[$index]++;
        } else {
            $out[$index] = 1;
        }
    }
}

echo "Original array:<br/>";
echo '<pre>';print_r($arr);echo '</pre>';

echo "Counted values:<br/>";
echo '<pre>';print_r($out);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Output:

Original array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 5
            [3] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 
            [3] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 5
            [3] => 5
        )

)

Counted values:

Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [5] => 3
    [] => 3
    [4] => 1
    [2] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sum of the values, although this does assume that all the arrays have the same columns as the first row...

```
$data = '[
  {"0":1, "1":5, "3":null},
  {"0":4, "1":null, "3":2},
  {"0":null, "1":5, "3":5}
]';

$data = json_decode($data, true);
$out = array();
foreach ( array_keys($data[0]) as $key ) {
    $out[$key] = array_sum(array_column($data, $key));
}
print_r(json_encode($out));
```

This looks at the first row of your data and gets a list of the columns(using `array_keys()`), then it extracts the values for this column (using `array_column()`) from the overall array and adds the values together (using `array_sum()`).

The output is...

```
{"0":5,"1":10,"3":7}
```

**Update:**
After question edit...

```
$data = '[
  {"0":1, "1":5, "3":null},
  {"0":4, "1":null, "3":null},
  {"0":null, "1":5, "3":5}
]';

$data = json_decode($data, true);
$out = array();
foreach ( array_keys($data[0]) as $key ) {
    $out[$key] = 0;
    foreach ( array_column($data, $key) as $value ) {
        if ( $value )   {
            $out[$key]++;
        }
    }
}
print_r(json_encode($out));
```

Outputs...

```
{"0":2,"1":2,"3":1}
```

Uses a similar principle, but just loops through each column and keeps count of ones that contain a value.

Or a shorter version...

```
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$out = array();
foreach ( array_keys($data[0]) as $key ) {
    $out[$key] = count(array_filter(array_column($data, $key)));
}
print_r(json_encode($out));
```

Comment: Please don't change the question, you originally had sum and your expected output was sum.  I've added a new version of the code, but realise that people are giving their time for free and not paid to do these things.

Comment: This will break when any key is not present  in any one of the array.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC I know, that's why I put the comment in the first line of the answer about assuming all rows are based on the same columns.

Comment: @NigelRen tried that code, a real scenario may not be like this. It will be helpful for others if you can update your code for that also.

Answer (score 0):

Although recursion is not strictly needed, `array_walk_recursive()` offers a direct path to the second level associative data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cTpsR))

```
$result = [];
array_walk_recursive(
    $array,
    function($v, $k) use(&$result) {
        $result[$k] = ($result[$k] ?? 0) + ($v !== null);
    }
);
var_export($result);
```

Otherwise, nested loops can be used to access the rows' data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/s6Yil))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
        $result[$k] = ($result[$k] ?? 0) + ($v !== null);
    }
}
var_export($result);
```